# User Group Setup

Tags: joomla, acl, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have created a user group "Sub-Users" under the "Registered" user group.
Now I have created and assigned some menus for Registered group and Sub-Users group.

Now when I logged in as Registered user I can't see the Sub-Users group menus and its OK for me,
But when I logged in as Sub-User group I can see the both menus (Registered & Sub User Group) and its not OK for me.

Now I am looking for solution if I logged in as Sub User I want to see only Sub User menus.

Can you please let me know if there is any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Access control is managed via 'viewing access levels' as opposed to 'user groups'

If you haven't already done so, check Users > Access Levels. Open the level names in question and check which groups you have configured for each access level.

Good luck!